# Saving information parsed from Firebase for offline viewing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a functionality to my app which ensures that if the user connects to the internet even once then the info parsed from the Firebase (in this case, an ArrayList object in which each object has 3 string variables) can be saved somehow (either using sharedPreferences or file or any other method) so that the next the time user opens the app without internet connection, then this already parsed data should be displayed and if there is internet connection, then it should work normally.

For this purpose, I came to know about disk persistence, but it is not working. Here is my code

```
package in.protechlabz.www.yavatmalindicatorserver;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Nikesh on 23/12/2016.
 */
public class ContactListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<ContactData> generalList = new ArrayList<ContactData>();

    Intent intent;
    private int listItemSelector=0; // This variable will be used to store information obtained from
    // intent regarding which listview to be loaded
    private AdView mAdView2;
    Firebase myFirebaseRef;
    private ArrayAdapter<ContactData> listItemAdapter;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.directory_list);

        /* Admob related important code*/
        mAdView2 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);


        // Extract information from intent for listItemSelector
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null) {
            listItemSelector = extras.getInt("ListPosition");
        }

        //if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ContactListActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();

            //Adding information to individual lists
        /*Firebase related code*/
            myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://yavatmalindicatorserver.firebaseio.com");
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


            myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    generalList.clear();
                    switch (listItemSelector) {

                        case 1:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Hotels and Lodges").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Banks").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Tours and Travels").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Function Halls").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Hospitals").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Educational Institutes").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Medicals").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Government Offices").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Press").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                    }
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Railways (Dhamangaon)").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;

                        // From here emergency list
                        case 11:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Police Station").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Fire Brigade").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Ambulance").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Blood Banks").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 15:
                            for (DataSnapshot eachContact : snapshot.child("Snake Friends").getChildren()) {
                                ContactData tempData = eachContact.getValue(ContactData.class);
                                generalList.add(tempData);
                            }
                            break;


                    }


                    listItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.hide();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
                }
            });
        //}else {

           // Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry No Internet Connection",
             //       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //finish();
        //}

        listItemAdapter = new ContactDataAdapter(this,R.layout.eachcontact_row,generalList);
        ListView myContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.directoryList);

        //For card view
        myContactList.addHeaderView(new View(this));
        myContactList.addFooterView(new View(this));

        myContactList.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);

        myContactList.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        ContactData singleItem = (ContactData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String number = singleItem.getTelephone();

                        // Parse only one number if multiple numbers present
                        int indexOfComma = number.indexOf(",");

                        if(indexOfComma != -1) {
                            number = number.substring(0,indexOfComma);
                        }

                        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );




    }

    /*public boolean isNetworkAvailable(final Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }*/
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you seen this -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities --?

Comment: Yes I have exactly seen that article and included in my code as well but its not working

Comment: You should call '.keepSynced(true);' in the references that you want to save in cache, or create your own local DB for your app.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple but very handy library for that purpose. It's called [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo). After adding it to your project, you can simply call `putListObject()` on your instance of TinyDB so your data gets saved.

Good luck with that